# Questions about Proxy Rotation

Tags: apify

I have developed a crawler act by using PuppeteerCrawler, currently with min. and max. concurrency 1 and I have a few questions:

1. Is proxy rotation activated by default or do I have to activate it and how?
2. If proxy rotation is active, how can I see it working, for example where can I get the used IP?
3. When is proxy rotation triggered, if a new crawler is created, or if a new tab is opened?

Best regrads,
Wulfgääng

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need to set maxConcurrency to 1. Instead you can play with `puppeteerPoolOptions` option to control chromium (or chrome) instances because proxy is tied to them (see answer 1).

1. Proxy rotation isn't enabled by default. To enable it you need to setup PuppeteerCrawler as follow:

```js
const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
   ... // code omitted for brevity
   puppeteerPoolOptions: {
       maxOpenPagesPerInstance: 1,
       retireInstanceAfterRequestCount: 3,
       killInstanceAfterSecs: 5,
   },
   launchPuppeteerFunction: () => {
       return Apify.launchPuppeteer({
           useApifyProxy: true,
           // Use a new proxy with a new IP address for each new Chrome instance
           apifyProxySession: Math.random().toString() ,
       })
       // Or you can use proxyUrl option
       // const proxyUrl = Apify.getApifyProxyUrl({ /*groups,*/ session: Math.random().toString() })
       // return Apify.launchPuppeteer({
       //    proxyUrl,
       // })
   },
   ...
});
```

2. You just need to log messages to the console `console.log()`. To get the IP of proxy use the following code:

```
...
const request = require('request-promise-native');
...
const session = Math.random().toString();
const proxy = Apify.getApifyProxyUrl({ /*groups,*/ session })
const { clientIp } = await request({ url: 'https://api.apify.com/v2/browser-info', proxy, json: true });
```

3. When using `PuppeteerCrawler`, the underlying instance of `PuppeteerPool` takes care of creating and handling chromium (or chrome) instances. Those chromium instances are launched via Puppeteer with or without proxy settings (depending on the options passed to `PuppeteerCrawler`).